# Where is the list of hotkey for TortoiseHG (Mercurial SCV)

Tags: user-interface, mercurial, shortcut, tortoisehg

I found some common hotkeys whome helps use TortoiseHG. But I would like know where is the list of all keybindings?

eg: `Ctrl + D` make duplicate of string in field where entering commit

Thx

Comment: I don't understand the vote to close for being off topic. This question is obviously about "software tools commonly used by programmers" which are on topic. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: why not ? This is instrument of programmers. You can don't send this link. Because stackoverflow has tag "tortoiseHG" and I have bad read english. And other, other reasons.. By the way... Can I ask you? Do you know somethings hot keys for TortoiseHG (powered on Mercurial HG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, found this https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/wiki/KeySequences
(says last updated 2013)

it doesn't include `Ctrl+D` and points to Qt standard keystrokes, which doesn't mention it either
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#standard-shortcuts